# How to make a Ubuntu LiveCD (on a USB)

Tags: live-cd

I would like to make a LiveCD (on a USB flash drive) so I can run GParted and edit my partitions.

How would I make the LiveCD? Since this is not windows, I can't use the normal one on `ubuntu.com` since it has `wubi.exe` which is the installer only for windows, any Linux version or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have access to a machine running Ubuntu already?

If so hit the Windows/Meta key and type 'disk' in to unity

the first option should be 'Startup Disk Creator' - choose this.

then point the creator to an iso you would like make bootable and choose the USB drive (plugged in to your machine) that you would like to boot from.

Put your USB disk into you USB slot at boot time - hit F12 (or the options that allows you to choose your boot device).  This should boot your live disk

Does this answer you question?  Is this what you are asking

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I didn't know there was a Startup Disk Creator , I thought I would need a 3rd Party Program ,Though I know how to boot from it